# How to implement HTTP basic authentication and custom request headers for video URLs in Qt app?

Tags: qt4.7, symbian3, meego-harmattan

1)      How to properly  implement supplying authentication parameters in http request headers, some using http basic authentication headers, some custom headers, for an URL that is used as video source for video playback , in Qt 4.7 app targeted for Symbian and MeeGo?

2)      Is it possible to open a video URL that requires http basic authentication or custom request headers using the Video player application that comes with the Symbian^3 and MeeGo Devices, and can this be launched from Qt 4.7 app?

Both streaming and downloading the video file cases are of interest to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QNetworkAccessManager` for this purpose:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qnetworkaccessmanager.html

It has a bunch of handy methods for making HTTP requests and receiving responses.